# How to extract data from apps

Tags: python, sql, database

I'm a an aspiring data analyst, and I've learned to use SQL, spreasheets, Python, R and more softwares in order to do succesful analyses. However, there's one thing I haven't found properly explained anywhere.

**As long as I'm given a dataset or access to a database, everything's fine. But what if I wanted to get some data myself? For example, if I were using an android sporting app - how would I extract the data in order to track my progress or something in that sense, how would I do it?**

I know this question is very general, and I apologise for that. You don't need to explain the whole process for me. If you could just refer me to some resources so that I could learn it on my own, I'd be very grateful.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a data engineer, there's many ways you can tackle this and depends on your application, but generally what I'd do is:

- Setup an SQL database (cloud providers like AWS, GCP or Azure are good options to start)
- Read about [HTTP Requests](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=protocol-http-requests)
- If using Python, check out the requests, pandas and numpy libraries

Again, there's a lot of things going on, but learning these could provide a basic start for most applications under data analysis.

Also, you may be interested in [data engineering](https://www.edureka.co/blog/data-analyst-vs-data-engineer-vs-data-scientist/)